# exception Convert ToInt32 dans c#

Tags: c#

I have this code but  but when I run the program gives me this error System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format'.

```
      public static void Main(string[] args)
    { 

        string a =TextFormater("Teste teste ");

        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
     public static string TextFormater(string ChaineTextArea)
    {
        string val = string.Empty;
        string Valreturn = string.Empty;
        int result;
        for (int i = 0; i <= ChaineTextArea.Length; i++)
        {
            val = ChaineTextArea.Substring(i, 1);    
            var chars = val.ToCharArray();

            result = Convert.ToInt32(val);

            if (result != 13)
            {
                Valreturn= val;
            }

            else
            {
                Valreturn= "<br>" + val;
            }
        }
        return Valreturn;
    }
```

Comment: error:System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
   at Rextester.Program.TextFormater(String ChaineTextArea)
   at Rextester.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: What part of "Teste teste " do you believe to be a number?

Comment: try to convert an alphabet to number?

Comment: `result = Convert.ToInt32(val);` < converting text....

Comment: What you are trying to do with this piece of code?

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do `public static string TextFormater(string ChaineTextArea) => ChaineTextArea.Replace("\n", "<br>");`? [I don't think this formatting strategy will get you very far, though.]

Answer (score 0):

Your input is not a valid format for converting to Integer. However if you need the ASCII value of those characters, that can be arranged by this

```
string input = "Teste teste "; 
var values = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
foreach(var item in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Hope that will help.

Comment: Well, can you please tell me what was the question? and what he tried to do

Comment: I bet he don't know what he want to do. Well I think he will get some idea now

Comment: So you are answering here for an unknown question, isn't it?

Comment: Not really, I think that he wants to do something like that, that's why i answered.

Comment: Why would someone want to know the ASCII code units for a UTF-16 `string` that has been converted to the ASCII character set with the potential for silent data loss?

Answer (score 0):

is not valid format I corrected by this code and is working

```
  val = ChaineTextArea.Substring(i, 1);    
char []chars = val.ToCharArray();
result = Convert.ToInt32(chars[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it to convert `int.Parse(val)`

or

```
Int32.TryParse(val, out number);
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. If you are trying to convert string to int then it is invalid conversion but you think if the val maybe int or string then try to use int.TryParse